# Convert a list of tuples to a dictionary, based on tuple values

Tags: python

I have a little problem, maybe dumb, but it seems I can't solve it.

I have a list of objects that have members, but let's say my list is this:

```py
l = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (3, 'a')]
```

I want to "gather" all elements based on the value I choose, and to put them into a dictionary based on that value/key (can be both the first or the second value of the tuple).

For example, if I want to gather the values based on the first element, I want something like that:

```py
{1: [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c')], 2: [(2, 'a')], 3: [(3, 'a')]}
```

However, what I achieved until now is this:

```py
>>> {k:v for k,v in zip([e[0] for e in l], l)}
{1: (1, 'c'), 2: (2, 'a'), 3: (3, 'a')}
```

Can somebody please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought would be using `defaultdict(list)` (efficient, in linear time), which does exactly what you were trying to do:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dic = defaultdict(list)
l = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (3, 'a')]
for item in l:
    dic[item[0]].append(item)
```

output

```
defaultdict(list,{1: [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c')], 2: [(2, 'a')], 3: [(3, 'a')]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here with list comprehension, oneliner:

```
l = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (3, 'a')]

print (dict([(x[0], [y for y in l if y[0] == x[0]]) for x in l]))
```

Output:

```
{1: [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c')], 2: [(2, 'a')], 3: [(3, 'a')]}
```

Comment: The power of list comprehension... Thank you very much, it was easier than I thought

Comment: This is absolutely not a good approach, it is unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: @crissal this is an example of *where a list comprehension **isn't** powerful*. It forces you to use a quadratic time algorithm when this can be achieved trivially in linear time

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
l = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (3, 'a')]
output_dict = dict()

for item in l:
    if item[0] in output_dict:
        output_dict[item[0]].append(item)
        continue
    output_dict[item[0]] = [item]

print(output_dict)
```

Answer (score -2):

First create a dico with list inside :

```
l = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (3, 'a')]
dico={}
for i in range(4):
    dico[i]=[]
```

Then fill this dico

```
for i in l:
    dico[i[0]].append(i)
```